# Tableau - Clean Up All Users Group

Tags: tableau-api

I added a group to a site. The users were then added to the All Users group. I then removed the group, but the users remained.

Is there anyway to clean this up so that the users get deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you want to delete the users that were in the group?

Creating and deleting groups does not create or delete users. To delete users you need to go to the users tab and select the users you want to delete.

Also, keep in mind that if the user owns content you will get a message saying:

> "[user] was unlicensed" instead of the expected “[user] was deleted” 
>   message.
>
> The “unlicensed” message displays because the user who you want to
>   delete is a workbook or project owner and therefore cannot be deleted.
>   In other words, a user can only be permanently deleted from Tableau
>   Server if he or she no longer owns a workbook or project.

See more here: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/deleting-user-from-tableau-server

Comment: My problem likes with the fact let's say User A to User Z ONLY exist in an AD group called Group A. You add them to a site. You later delete the group, for whatever reason. Those Users (User A to User Z) are still in the "All Users" group.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is not good with Active Directory when it comes to removing users. If you ADD Active Directory account and set up sync, it will add a new user who will be added in AD group but once you remove AD group it will not remove any users who were in AD group.

In order to remove those users, you need to go to all users and delete the Users manually which defeats the purpose of using AD groups.